# How do I change textcolor on a string (Listview grouping letters) in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am following this project and it works very good: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-Monkeys

But I would like to change the textcolor on the letters on the right side:

[image]

They are blue by default but is there a way to change this?

`public string NameSort => Name[0].ToString();`

The letters are made with a string but I am unsure how to change the textcolor of it.

Comment: You have to do it via custom renderer. The jump list is an iOS only feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass the `Xamarin.Forms` iOS-based `ListViewRenderer` and set the `SectionIndexColor` and/or `SectionIndexBackgroundColor`:

```
public class ListViewExRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        (Control as UITableView).SectionIndexColor = UIColor.Red;
        (Control as UITableView).SectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
        base.LayoutSubviews();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Having trouble getting it to change color. This is what I currently have: http://pastebin.com/thaLZNhP

Comment: You are using the wrong class, the first class is the type of Form's control that this renderer is used for: i.e. `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(ListViewExRenderer))]
`

Comment: ... ah yeah of course. I was a bit to hesitant so i did not check it out throughly. Thanks a ton!